# JS: Luxon - Change human readable time String

Tags: javascript, luxon

I switched from *moment.js* to *luxon.js*. I tested some stuff with human readable timestamps,
for instance instead of showing the absolute time `11:50:39` it says `2 minutes ago` or `37 seconds ago`.

I can do this very easily using luxon's `toRelative()` function.

But I have one issue: When there is data which is updated every second, the *relative* time (now - timestamp) is **0** seconds. The `toRelative()` function returns `"in 0 seconds"`. But  would like to prefer that it returns something like `"Now"`.

```
// Testing relative time difference of 0 seconds
let date = DateTime.local()
console.log(date.toRelative({base: date})); // returns "in 0 seconds"
```

Is there any way to change this for this specific case? Or is there any workaround?

Comment: `date.toRelativeCalendar({base: date, unit: 'seconds'})` displays `now`, but I don't know if  [`toRelativeCalendar`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toRelativeCalendar) covers your needs  and if it's configurable enough.

Comment: This seems quite nice, but is there a way to display `"now"` and display `X seconds ago`, `X minutes ago`, `x hours ago` also? So when I use `unit: 'seconds'` its always displayed as seconds, event when seconds > 60 (then I want minutes).

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find a _native_ way to get both `now` and `X seconds ago`

Comment: I do it now by determining the duration in seconds between the two dates and then use `toRelative()` (duration > 0) and `toRelativeCalendar`. Seems to be the only solution so far. Thanks for your help!